# Exception handling need to resume called function

Tags: vb.net, exception

In VB.Net,

I am having function x() & function y(). x() calls y().

- Since x() is making some crucial operation it needs to finish at any
  cost ( I am dealing with money related transaction here).
- But in y() , i am calling some 3rd party web service for obtaining
  additional info.
- Even if y() fails, i need to resume with x().
- I need to use object returned from y() in x().
- If y() encounters exception, what should i return if there is any exception ?
- I want it to return to x , no matter i have returned null from y().

How can i structure y() code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to structure your code with a Try Catch Block inside Y like this:

```
Public Sub X()
    Try
         ### Do some crucial operation here
         Dim obj = Y() 'call Y
         If Not obj Is Nothing Then
             'do some operation on obj if the call to Y succeeded
         End If
         ### Do more crucial operation here - this runs even if Y throws an exception
    Catch ex As Exception
        'x failed for some reason - log the ex.StackTrace and ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub

Public Function Y() As Object
    Try
        Dim obj As New Object
        'do y here
        Return obj
    Catch ex As Exception
        'ignore any error that occurs calling y
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Crucial operation finishes only after executing y() but it has to start before y().

Comment: Problem is how to structure y() ?

Comment: Y() returns an object. will you Return it on Catch block of y() ?